# Directly authenticating a user when hitting django admin login page

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-admin

I have a reactjs app that already has a user logged in. I attached a link to the web app that make the user able to access Django admin page, but for now it still requires the user to login.

I'd like to bypass the login as the user is already authenticated when logging into the react app.

How do I bypass the log in page and tell django that this user is already authenticated? What if I still want to get the email from `request`? where can I access the request object?

EDIT:

I should specify that I would like to check for auth token which I already have in my localStorage, then authenticate the external user directly. If the auth token is not present, I should still hit the django admin login page

EDIT2:

Created a custom page just to deal with Auth0 authentication. But I'm not sure what to do next. The `request.user` at this point is `AnonymousUser` which I can't really operate on. There is no way to identify who this is (but I can successfully check if this user has permission)

I plan to create a user and give it superuser permission? Is that the right approach?

EDIT3:

```
login(request, request.user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend')
return HttpResponseRedirect("/my/url")
```

and i got

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Is it part of the auth problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should not "bypass the login" you need to use authorized tokens... to identify that client whos is consuming the API is really you and not the anyone else

The process is really simple, once you send username and password to your backend (django) you will retorn one autorization token to your frontend (react) and every request from your frontend you will add it to header

Use django_rest_framework or something like that (as tastypie)

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: My user auth happens with auth0, so django's db might not have an existing user in the `auth_user` table. So essentially my django should only check for the auth token I guess (new to django and react, not sure how it works). How do I stick the auth token to request so I can pass it to django?

Comment: just add your Auth0 backend at your settings and use your auth token to process it

Comment: I got the permission check set up by creating a custom page just to handle that, but I'm stuck after this. It seems like I need to create a user and assign it superuser permission and log the newly created user in? Is this the right approach?

Comment: Let me ask you something, you are not nothing django model user? you doing your entire authentication and user classes ouside the django or outside User auth  from django?

Comment: The auth should happen in auth0, and when the permission checks passes, Django should just log this person in without any issue. That's the goal

Comment: I found my issue. When going from react app to my django, the request header doesn't get carried over, so when django checks for "Authorization Header", it finds nothing and returns error. I need to either invoke auth0 login at that point or find a way to pass auth header in request

Comment: The more I research, the more I can link your response to my question. However the problem still remains. It seems like I have CORS issue when making a GET from react to django since they exist on different domains. I'm now using a POST passing data in header, but now I'm getting 401 with `"Authentication credentials were not provided." when it definitely is`

Comment: its from same origin you will have CORS issue, you have to setup or backend to work with CORS